# Capturar momento en el que se cierra aplicación Android

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy realizando una aplicación con varias Activities. Mi pregunta es cómo puedo capturar el momento en el que el usuario cierra la aplicación, ya que en ese momento mi aplicación quiero que mande una petición HTTP a un servidor WEB.

Comment: Sabes de que forma vas a cerrar la aplicación, das clic en un botón o realizas onBackPressed()?

Comment: Que el usuario de al botón de aplicaciones abiertas y la cierre desde ahí.

Answer (score 2):

Si revisas el ciclo de vida de la `Activity` puede saber que método usar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método a utilizar sería [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

     //Realiza petición al detectar cierre de aplicación.

}
```

pero es importante que tomes en cuenta:

> Nota: ¡no cuente con que este método sea llamado como un lugar para
>   guardar datos! Por ejemplo, si una actividad es la edición de datos en
>   un proveedor de contenido, esas ediciones se deben confirmar en
>   `onPause()` o `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas buscando es la función onDestroy() que se llama una vez se cierra una activity, para que cumpla tu proposito deberías añadirlo en el activity principal de la app aunque hay muchos casos que te van a dar error. Te dejo aquí la [Documentación oficial del método](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método onDestroy() en tu clase de aplicación guía [Guía de clase de aplicación](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class)

Ó si quieres de un Activity o Fragment en específico debes conocer "Ciclo de Vida" de estos. 
Más info -> [Ciclo de vida de un activity](https://stories.devacademy.la/android-ciclo-de-vida-de-un-activity-b2a68c506961) y [Ciclo de vida de un Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es-419)